# How do I connect to my Brother MFC-6800 over USB?

Tags: 10.04, printing

How can I connect to my Brother MFC-6800 printer over USB?

*(I have an answer to this question and I'm posting it for the benefit of the next person, but please write a better answer if you can!)*

Answer (score 2):

I found the MFC-6800 in [this list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BrotherDriverPackaging) under "laser1".  So, then I installed the package [brother-lpr-drivers-laser1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/brother-lpr-drivers-laser1) using the Software Center.  After that, when I added the printer, Ubuntu automatically recognized it.